# In Magento i am setting up promo code

Tags: php, magento, promotion-code

I want to apply my code only on the prize of that or those products which i have mention while creating promo code. it works fine if i have only that or those product(s) in cart but if 
there is any other product in the cart which is not mention in promo code rule it apply on that product prize as well is there any way to apply promo code only on those product prize not on whole cart.

need your help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Under shopping cart price rules, head to Actions.

You have this work as a Fixed amount discount, or a percentage.
Your rules on the bottom should be SKU CONTAINS for configurable products, or IS ONE OF if your store is stocked with simple products.

This worked for me in enterprise 1.12.0.2, but may be different on community or go editions.